# Reading in data of user specified length in C

Tags: c, file-io, user-input

I am trying to create a program that will read in data from multiple text files and compare the data from each file. Currently I am stuck trying to read from a file with an unknown number of columns and row, until the user specifics the length at run time.

In the past I have used fscanf, but it has always had how many columns and what type of variable they were hardwired into the program, ie `fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c)`. Is it possible to use something so that I don't have to inherently program into the code say 3 double indicators? Currently I have it so the user inputs the number of files, columns in each file and rows. The idea of the program is to always compare similar files, so they need to always have the same format, ie # of rows and # of columns.

Current code if it helps:

```
int main(){
/* Ask for # of files */
printf("\nHow many files are you comparing\n");
int filnum;
scanf("%d",&filnum);

/* Ask for # of columns */
printf("How many columns of data are there?\n");
int colnum;
scanf("%d",&colnum);

/* Ask for length of rows */
printf("How many rows of data are there?\n");
int rownum;
scanf("%d",&rownum);

/* Read in file names */
char filea[filnum][50];
int i;
for (i=0; i<filnum; i++) {
    char temp[50];
    printf("Eneter file #%d please.\n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",temp);
    if(strlen(temp)>50){
        printf("Please shorten file to less than 50 char");
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(filea[i],temp);
}

/* Create data array on heap */
double* data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*rownum*colnum*filnum);

/* Start opening files and reading in data */
for (i=0; i<filnum; i++) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filea[i],"r");
    if (fp==NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file #%d",i+1);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Attempt */
    int j,k;
    for (j=0; j<rownum; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<colnum; k++) {
            fscanf(fp," %lf",&data[i*rownum*colnum + j*colnum + k]);
            printf("%lf, ",data[i*rownum*colnum + j*colnum + k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

free(data);


return 0;
}
```

Extra awesome would be somehow getting rid of having to eneter # of columns and # of rows, but that's getting ahead of myself I guess. Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be:

```
for (i=0; i<max; i++)
{
  fscanf (fp, " %f", &var[i])
}
```

You should allocate `var` to the length of at least `max` with type `double` of `float`

Or read an entire line with `fgets` then use `strtok` and `strtod` to get the floating point numbers.